# Can a function be passed as a default parameter somehow?

Tags: php

I know I can keep $at = false as default and later set the $at variable again if $at == false,but I was keen to know if there is some other shortcut than that .

```
public function insert_user_to_user_reference($referrer_id,$referee_id,$at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
{
    //some code here ...
}
```

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. I initially thought of a callback. Do you want to set `$at` to some date inside the method if `$at` was `false` in the first place?

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to set the parameter default value to something which isn't  a constant value (i.e. using a function value as in `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't call a function to provide a default argument value. [As the docs put it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default), "*The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.*"

I think an idomatic way to write the function you want would be with a default null value, and a docblock to explain the meaning of null, i.e.:

```
/**
 * @param ?string $at reference creation time in Y-m-d H:i:s format, or null for now.
 */
 public function insert_user_to_user_reference(
    string $referrer_id,
    string $referee_id,
    ?string $at = null
 )
 {
     if ($at === null) {
         $at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     }
     //some code here ...
 }
```

Comment: I know how to set default later, but some times there are 3 to 4 defaults in a function,and I am redefining a lot of function in an existing code base.I was looking for a shortcut.
Anyway, thanks for the response.